# Can a rectifiable Jordan curve $\Gamma$ be approximated with a Jordan polygon $P$ which is contained in the interior of $\Gamma$?

Tags: general-topology, approximation, curves, polygons, bounded-variation

Consider a rectifiable Jordan curve $\Gamma$ and let $\gamma: S^1 \rightarrow \Gamma$ be a homeomorphism. Moreover, let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\Gamma$ be the interior of $\Gamma$.  For each $\varepsilon>0$, is there a Jordan polygon $P \subset \Omega \cup \Gamma$ (which need not be inscribed in $\Gamma$, although preferably it should be) and a homeomorphism $\rho: S^1 \rightarrow P$ such that

$$\max_{t \in S^1} |\gamma(t) - \rho(t)|< \varepsilon \quad \text{and} \quad |L(\Gamma)-L(P)|< \varepsilon$$

where $L$ stands for length? If we abolish the condition $P \subset \Omega \cup \Gamma$, then the answer is yes. However, with this condition I am not sure if this holds true.

Comment: Yes, it's true.  It's proven in Voxman and Christenson's Aspects of Topology in the course of proving the Schoenflies/Annulus Theorems.  However, if you already have the Schoenflies Theorem at your disposal then it's totally trivial, using uniform convergence of a sequence of circles converging to your $\Gamma$ from within, and then approximating one that's close enough with a polygon contained in $\Omega$, which is always possible.